# 2012 Great Wall v200

Tags: engine, fuel-injection

I have no idea how to explain this but I'll try my best! So, a few weekends ago, around 4am, I was driving my 2012 Great Wall v200 to work and it was going fine. Then, on Sunday, I went to Blacktown shops and around 80-100 km/h it started losing power and was being weird but it stopped after 5 minutes!nThen, on Monday, I went to drive to work and my car wouldn't even drive out of the driveway and had no power in it, it was blowing out white and black smoke! I had to rev it hard to even move it!!

So I rang my dad and he said take the chip out (which he put in). So, I did and the van was going better than ever! But once I got back on the m4, it started losing power again, and now my car shakes heavily and barely drives!! My dad says it's the injectors or something to do with fuel but I have no idea! Because I drove it to Winsor the other day with no problems, but then all the problems just come back.

Comment: Mine has just done the same. Can you please tell me what the problem was in the end. Was it a costly repair?